# Python: Run 2 processes in parallel then wait for all with timeout

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Looking for some best practices for the following python3 task:

- run process `program1` in non-blocking mode
- run process `program2` in non-blocking mode
- wait for all or kill them after timeout exceeded

I reckon I know how to do it for 1 process:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('program1', shell=True)
try:
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(timeout=200)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as t:
    print(t)
    p.kill()
    outs, errs = p.communicate()
```

However I can't expand this approach for 2-processes case, because `p.communicate` blocks until `program1` ends or timeout exceeds.

Also I'd like to know immediately if one of the programs fails.

Python3, OS Linux

**UPD** I need to implement it wisely, without any busy loops, threads etc

Answer (score 0):

Process has a `join()` method similar to threads. So, in your case:

```
proc_1 = Process(target=my_func_1)
proc_2 = Process(target=my_func_2)

for proc in [proc_1, proc_2]:
    proc.start()

# They are doing their thing and when they've completed they will join the 
# main process and your main program can resume
for proc in [proc_1, proc_2]:
    proc.join()
```

Comment: I'm going to run a program (like via shell), not just a python function. So threads are not an option. And still I need specify timeout to prevent from hanging

Comment: I was just saying like with threads, `Process` have a `join()` method. You don't have to use threads. And `join()` can take a timeout. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join